# Latex Listing: Define Font

Tags: latex, listings

How do I define a font to a listing?

I would like one font on the line numbers (Sans 6pt) and another (Monospace (8pt) on the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the style of the line numbers using the following command:

```
\lstdefinestyle{numbers}{numberstyle=\tiny}
```

The code appearance can be defined using:

```
\lstset{basicstyle=\small}
```

You can replace `\tiny` and `\small` by your own style specifications.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [listings](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/) or [fancyvrb](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyvrb/) package.